# Flash AS3 MouseOver not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am having trouble getting a MOUSE_OVER event to fire consistently and as intended. I have a custom cursor (movieclip) attached to my mouse and it has 2 frames (1st frame cursor is black and second frame it is white).

Here is code from my cursor script:

```
    private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
    {
        gotoAndStop(1);
        this.mouseChildren = false;
        this.mouseEnabled = false;
    }
    public function rollover():void
    {
        gotoAndStop(2);
        trace("change cursor");
    }
```

Here is the class for an object that will react when the cursor moves over it:

```
public class DoorHS01 extends MovieClip
{
    public var cursor:Cursor;
    public function DoorHS01() 
    {
        cursor = new Cursor();

        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, rollover);
    }

    public function rollover(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        cursor.rollover();
        trace("rollover");
    }
}
```

}

So in the DoorHS01 class the MouseEvent doesn't always fire or it will be really delayed. The cursor.rollever function gets called and it executes in the cursor class (I know from the traces) but the cursor never changes.

What am I missing?

Comment: I thought maybe that the custom cursor was causing issues so I tried adding all of the movieclips to an array like so: `_hotSpotArr = [mc1, mc2]` and then just checking for collision in the enterframe like so: `for (var i:Number = 0; i < _hotSpotArr.length; i++)
    {
     if (cursor.hitTestObject(_hotSpotArr[i]))
     {
      cursor.gotoAndStop(2);
     }
     else (cursor.hitTestObject(_hotSpotArr[1]))
     {
      cursor.gotoAndStop(1);
     }
    }` But that doesn't seem to be working either...

Comment: ^What I meant to say is it only works with mc2 but not mc1

Comment: in **DoorHS01** Since you made a `cursor = new Cursor();` instead of a vague `this.` why not follow that with a specific `cursor.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, rollover);` to guarantee you are talking to cursor? You dont need code inside the cursor movieclip itself (except for a `stop();` on its frame 1 to stop auto-play). Finally in that **DoorHS01** instead of `cursor.rollover()` just do a `cursor.gotoAndStop(2);`.. does that help?

Comment: ^I decided I didn't want to do a class for every single object in the game that would chance the cursor and instead will just add them to an array and check collision with the cursor. BUT I just noticed something super odd....In my cursor class I removed all the functions except for the OnAddedToStage one you see above. I then removed the gotoAndStop(1) command just to watch the cursor "blink" (switch back and forth between frame 1 (black cursor) to frame 2 (white cursor)....and it stays on frame 1. Why? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Never mind I fixed it. Damn I wish I could make a large post up top in this thread rather than only being able to add comments. I feel code in comments looks so bad... I may just have to start a new post. My question in my first comment ^^^^ is what I'm having trouble with. I don't understand why the cursor will only change with the second object in the array but not the first. Trace commands show it recognizes the first object in the array within the loop...

Comment: @NickLozano as you noticed yourself: code in comments is a mess. Next time edit your question and add relevant information to it. Comments are second class citizens on this site. Think about them as if they could be deleted at any moment. As of now, this question is quite a mess. You should **post an answer** explaining what solved the problem. This way it becomes clear that this question has an answer.

Comment: @null I was able to come up with a solution and yes code in comments is a total mess. I would love to edit my question but I don't know how. How do you? Sorry I don't use this site often...

Comment: **Don't edit the answer into your question!** post the answer as an answer. Answering your own question is perfectly fine.

Comment: @null oh haha ok sorry I miss understood you. For future reference, you mentioned it was possible to edit a question...how would I do that?

Comment: Below the question, you have some links for **me**, they are `share edit close flag` they can be different for **you**, but `edit` should be available. Click it.

Comment: @null geez...I'm blind. Thank you null for all your help and patience. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I decided that the best way to achieve what I wanted was to test collision with my custom cursor rather than creating classes for everything object that needed a rollover function. I also currently do not know how many objects will require this rollover functionality as the designer I'm working with is still working out the game details so it is going to be easier to just add what is needed to an array when needed. I ended up going with this:

```
            for (var i:int = 0; i < _hotSpotArr.length; i++)
            {
                if (cursor.hitTestObject(_hotSpotArr[i]))
                {
                    cursor.gotoAndStop(2);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    cursor.gotoAndStop(1);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Just a +1 for solving your own question. I think you can achieve same effect by using `event.currentTarget` in the **rollOver** function. This will auto-detect which Display Object is being rolled-over and you can do **if/else** on it. Try `trace("rollover Obj was : " + e.currentTarget);` In your **rollOver** code to see what I mean,